# Error near 'DELIMITER $$'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, delimiter

when I change Delimeter from mysql console or MySQL Workbench I do not get any error,
but when I embed the same code in ruby on rails I get error

```
mysql> DELIMITER $$
mysql>
```

gives no error.

but

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(%Q{
    DELIMITER $$
})
```

gives:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$' at line 1:
```

Answer (score 5):

The [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15657150/2578505) is correct (Rails cannot execute `DELIMITER` because it is a MYSQL command), but @ishandutta2007's follow up question was not answered, so I'll answer that here.

`DELIMITER` is often used to wrap mysql function and procedure bodies; to achieve this in rails simply wrap the procedure body in it's own execute statement.

So for instance code that might read like:

```
execute <<-SQL
  DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS MyFunc;
  DELIMITER $$
  CREATE FUNCTION My Func
    . . .
  $$
  DELIMITER ;
SQL
```

Would instead become the following, with the multiple `execute` calls acting as the 'scoping' intended by redefining the delimiter:

```
execute 'DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS MyFunc'
execute <<-SQL
  CREATE FUNCTION My Func
    . . .
SQL
```

Answer (score 3):

`DELIMITER` is actually a MySQL command line setting, not SQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-commands.html. That means that you can't set the delimiter in this way.

On top of that, it wouldn't help if you could as `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` only allows you to execute one statement at a time out of the box (see http://www.seanr.ca/tech/?p=75).

Comment: then how do I execute the following from rails?[CODE]  
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE XYZ(IN t INT)
BEGIN 
         BLA BLA ...
END$$
DELIMITER ;[/CODE]